# Javascript: Changing src not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a function like this:

```
<img src="/images/icons/info.png"
width="18" height="18" class="iconbutton" alt="Add to Library" 
onclick="AddLibrary(12345,this.id); this.onclick=null;" />
```

The function then POSTS 12345 to another script and then is supposed to change the icon image:

```
function AddLibrary(pibnval,thisid) {
    $.post('/addlibrary.php', {
        pibn: pibnval
    }, function() {
    thisid.setAttribute('src', "/images/icons/tick.png");
    });
};
```

The POST works great, but the image does not change.

I also tried:
`document.getElementById(thisid).src = "/images/icons/tick.png";`
but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: where is the `id` of your `img` tag that you are passing to the function?

Comment: You should set an id to your image.

Comment: @jbl: No need, it's not used for anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agree he really doesn't need one, but then he should rename his variables, and call on this, instead of this.id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`thisid` is just a string, not an element. Change your `onclick` to:

```
onclick="AddLibrary(12345,this); this.onclick=null;"
```

(I removed the `.id`) and your `thisid` variable name to `img` or some such (just so it's not misleading):

```
function AddLibrary(pibnval,img) {
    $.post('/addlibrary.php', {
        pibn: pibnval
    }, function() {
    img.setAttribute('src', "/images/icons/tick.png");
    });
};
```

Other notes:

1. There's no reason to use `setAttribute` for this, image elements have a `src` property.
2. You don't put `;` after function declarations.
3. Consistent indentation helps you, and others, read your code.

So:

```
function AddLibrary(pibnval,img) {
    $.post('/addlibrary.php', {
        pibn: pibnval
    }, function() {
        img.src = "/images/icons/tick.png";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  - $('#'+ thisid).attr("src", '/images/icons/tick.png');

Also does your image have to be an image? because you could make it a div with a background image and set its width and height in css  then just  alter the css background like this

```
$('#'+ thisid).css({'background':'/images/icons/tick.png'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather attach the handler with JS (instead of inline) but you could change the code to this:

HTML

```
<img src="/images/icons/info.png"
width="18" height="18" class="iconbutton" alt="Add to Library" 
onclick="AddLibrary(event, 12345);" />
```

JS

```
function AddLibrary(e, pibnval) {
    var _this = e.target;

    $.post('/addlibrary.php', {
        pibn: pibnval
    }, function() {
        _this.setAttribute('src', "/images/icons/tick.png");
        _this.onclick = null;
    });
}
```